# Entity Framework Include error

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following Model objects

```
public class UserEntry
{
    public int UserEntryID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EntryPlayer> EntryPlayers { get; set; }
}
public class EntryPlayer
{
    public int EntryPlayerID { get; set; }
    public bool Captain { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserEntryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
}
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Group { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

My database schema looks like this:-

[image]

When I try and load a UserEntry using this code:-

```
UserEntry userEntry = this.db.UserEntries
                .Where(u => u.UserID == user.Id)
                .Include("EntryPlayers")
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the error:

```
Invalid column name 'Player_PlayerID'
```

If I change the `Player` property on my `UserEntry` object from:

```
public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public virtual int PlayerID { get; set; }
```

then my `UserEntry` object loads fine but obviously only has the `PlayerID` and not the whole `Player` object in it.

What do I need to change so that I can load the `Player` object within the `UserEntry`?

I also have this DatabaseInitializer class

```
namespace ACS.Models {

public class ACSDatabaseInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ACSContext>
{

   protected override void Seed(ACSContext context)
   {
       base.Seed(context);

       var players = new List<Player>();

       players.Add(new Player
       {
            PlayerID = 1, 
            FirstName = "Dave",
            MiddleInitial = "",
            LastName = "Smith",
            Group = 1,
            Team = "Team1",
            Score = 0
       });

       players.ForEach(p => context.Players.Add(p));

       context.SaveChanges();
     }
  }
}
```

and this Context class

```
namespace ACS.Models
{
    public class ACSContext : DbContext
    {
        public ACSContext()
        : base("name=ACS")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ACSContext>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserEntry> UserEntries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EntryPlayer> EntryPlayers { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Comment: How is the relationship defined in the Context?

Comment: You show the class model, not the database model. How did you build this model?

Comment: Started off as Code First but then I modified the database directly.  Have updated my question with some more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed both a PlayerID property and a Player property on my UserEntry object for this to work